# How to set color on MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am a beginner developer.
There was a slight problem with using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

Please look this [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuWVl.png).

At the bottom left of the chart in the photo,
How do I get rid of the five square colors that 
represent the color of each bar?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: I see this is your first Question on Stack Overflow, welcome! Please provide some code so we can see what you have tried and better understand the context of your question, which in turn will help us out to help you. Also see [How To ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask better question which lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can do it by this.

```
Legend legend = chart.getLegend();

legend.setEnabled(false);
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: It will work fine.
next time I'll try a little more alone Thank you!

Comment: @Jungyw93 you can accept answer if it's your solution.